# python add two dataframes with distinct column names

Tags: python, dataframe

How to add columns of two dataframes with distinct columns names

**df1**

```
  A B C
0 1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
```

**df2**

```
  D E F
0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
```

**This is not working, produces NaN's**

```
  df_result = df1.add(df2)
```

**what i need id df_result**

```
  X X X
0 2 3 4 
1 3 4 5
2 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the second dataframe has the same shape as the first, you can effectively ignore its index and column labels by converting it to a numpy array:

```
>>> df1.add(df2.to_numpy())
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  3  4  5
2  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, works perfectly, in this case dataframes have the same shape.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with loop:

```
for i in range(len(df1.columns)):
    df1[df1.columns[i]]=df1[df1.columns[i]]+df2[df2.columns[i]]
```

Result:

```
>>> df1
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  3  4  5
2  4  5  6
```